# Dynamic XAML load and external images and fonts

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this directory structure:

```
c:\app\program.exe
c:\app\assets\layout.xaml
c:\app\assets\videos\video.mp4
c:\app\assets\image\image.png
```

`layout.xaml` contains:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Image Source="assets/image/image.png" />
    <MediaElement Source="assets/videos/video.mp4" />
</Grid>
```

I load the `layout.xaml` using

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\app\assets\layout.xaml"))
{
    var pnl = (Panel)XamlReader.Load(sr.BaseStream);
    SomeOtherGrid.Children.Add(pnl);
}
```

The video shows up, but the image doesn't. How do you get the image to show up and why does the video show up and the image does not?

**Edit:**
I know about rows and how grids work. I know the video will be on top of the image in this scenario. What I'm asking is: Why does the video show up and the image doesn't. They are both sourced the exact same way.

**Edit 2:**
Apparently you have to use this ridiculous "pack" format for external resources:
`pack://siteoforigin:,,,/assets/videos/video.mp4`

This works for images and videos, but, it doesn't work with fonts:
`pack://siteoforigin:,,,/assets/fonts/intelclear/#Intel Clear Pro`

Why did they make this so convoluted? Why don't they just load from the root directory of the binary if it's a relative path?

Comment: It should work if you use a relative path from the directory of the *XAML file* that you load dynamically using the XamlReader.Load method as per my answer...

Comment: Doesn't work either. Try it -- make that directory structure and load it how I am in your code. Nothing works for images except that "pack" format. And **nothing** works for fonts with relative pathing.

Comment: I have already done this (except for fonts) and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaElement` will end up on top of the `Image` element since you add them to the same Grid.

You should use two RowDefinitions and set the `Grid.Row` attached property of the `MediaElement` to 1 to put it on the second row below the `Image`:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="image/image.png" />
    <MediaElement Source="videos/video.mp4" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

You should also remove the trailing "assets" from the path provided that the sample paths you posted are correct. The relative path to the image from `Layout.xaml` is "image.png".

Comment: I know about all the row definitions and things. I'm asking why does the video show up and the image doesn't. Even if I add rows and whatever, the image still doesn't show up, but the video does.

Comment: It works as expected for me. Please double check your paths. Are you for example sure that folder is named "image" and not "images"? Only you can tell. Do you only have a single "videos" folder?

Comment: How are you loading the XAML? if you do it from the EXE as a static resource, it works great. It's when you load it dynamically is when this starts happening.